# How to center external FitProportional Image on RDLC report?

Tags: image, rdlc

What is the easiest way to center an image (of unknown dimension) on an RDLC local view report in ASP.NET webform (Report Viewer 2012/Visual Studio 2013)?

The external image is set to FitProportional and its value is set to the URL of an image of unknown size and type. The image itself displays OK (most of the time) at the correct size but sits at top left of the image container. It seems to me that this control screams for two simple horizontal/vertical alignment properties. What kind of moron writes an image control that cannot at least be center aligned?

Is it possible to derive a custom Image control that overrides the drawing routine to manually center the image in the container? It would need to behave properly so the centering is also applied to the Word and PDF export (the only reason I'm using this awkward RDLC engine is for the "convenience" of Excel/Word/PDF export capabilities) (hence I cannot simply use CSS on the image to center it in the HTML output).

{rant} Sometimes the image is displayed with width=1 in HTML. Presumably this is something to do with delays in fetching the external image or some such lame excuse, so I probably have to further pollute my system with coding gymnastics to avoid that problem too. The main container layout is also easily messed up when changing zoom levels, and it really does not know how to size itself properly. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, if my CSS is messing it up or if it really is a just a badly implemented horror. {/rant}

Comment: Try checking [RDLC Reports Proportional Image Alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258225/rdlc-reports-proportional-image-alignment?rq=1). It is the best answer that I have seen so far.

Comment: Yes, it seems the answer is it cannot be done, you must either fiddle the position/padding manually or re-scale the image manually. In my project it was simpler to re-scale the images, which avoids extra code in the report.