# Center external image on RDLC with dynamic padding

Tags: rdlc

I have a problem centering my image on the RDLC report. I'm using image control and external source (path) for the image but I don't know the size of the image and I want to keep the actual size of the image but centered in image control. Is there any option that I can read image width in expression for left padding?

My idea is to read image size and I know image control size, so I can set left padding as (control size - image size) / 2.
Any other idea is welcome.

Comment: Similar question has been asked before, you can integrate your idea with this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17863474/6670491

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RDLC Reports Proportional Image Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258225/rdlc-reports-proportional-image-alignment)